# Get the right type in a function from multiple possible type in typescript

Tags: typescript, types

I'm having a bit of trouble figuring out how to solve my problem, despite the many answers I've already see on similar subjects.

I have the following types -- I'll add more later (one for each form roughly):

```js
export interface FormError {
  formError: string
}

export interface InputState<T> {
  value: T
  onError: boolean
  validation: FormDataValidation[] | undefined
  errorMessage?: string
}

export interface WorkoutForm extends FormError {
  trainingType: InputState<trainingType>
  name: InputState<string>
  date: InputState<string>
}

export interface LoginForm extends FormError {
  email: InputState<string>
  password: InputState<string>
}
```

I have the following function where I'd like to be able to use a "generic" type so that I can use it with `WorkoutForm` or with `LoginForm` or with others that I'll create later.

I've tried to solve my problem with `T` but my linter gives me lots of errors every time.

```js
public validate<T>(formData: T, index: Exclude<keyof T, 'formError'>): T {
    const validation = formData[index].validation; // << Property 'validation' does not exist on type 'T[Exclude ]'
    // ....... code
    return formData;
  }
```

I'd like to be able to use it like this, for example:

```js
function handleFormData(index: Exclude<keyof LoginForm, 'formError'>, value: string): void {
  // ... some code
  const currentFormData = formData; // currentFormData type is LoginForm
  currentFormData[index].value = value;
  const validatedData = FormValidation.getInstance().validate<LoginForm>(currentFormData, index);
  // ... some code
}
```

Any tips or idea to solve this problem?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mqpkYN) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz yeah it's look pretty ok :)

Comment: I used `unknown` in place of the `any` for avoiding another error and forced me to check the type, but everything working great; thanks mate !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make `validate()` [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in both `T`, the type of `formData`, as well as `K`, the type of `index`.  Additionally, you should [constrain](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) `T` and `K` so that `K` is a keylike type, and `T` is known to be an object with a property whose key type is `K` and whose value type is some `InputState<any>` (you can use `unknown` instead of `any` as long as `InputState<T>` is *covariant* in `T`, see [Difference between Variance, Covariance, Contravariance and Bivariance in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66410115/2887218) for more information).  That can be written as  `Record<K, InputState<any>>` using the [`Record<K, V>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type).  Like so:

```
function validate<
  T extends Record<K, InputState<any>>,
  K extends PropertyKey>(
    formData: T, index: K): T {
  const validation = formData[index].validation;
  return formData;
}
```

That compiles with no error, and now the rest of your code behaves as desired.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&jsx=0&ts=5.1.3#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHsoFsCiUqbIDeAUMsjJrvpgFzIDOYUoA5iQL4kmiSyIoAkiAAOAVzABlMHEgAeACoA+YmWQA3OABsxEegrXoQeAlHoAjdOi0Q4INZq3AAJrOBH6GbABFZcAGraLm5GANoAusgAPshiIM4QMKAQzmrQpgCyEAwMcKwQAPz0TCwg7Fw84NDwSGhUvjKBTq5g7iCq5AAexcxsANyc3LzVAsgA6pgA1ugSXljIEJ2Q8Qx12CaEpOTMcKBsCgCeInrIwuJSMvIgYljm0EpqIHBYJ2cS0rIQciVsD+Qtr1E70uXx+ZQeFWG-FqABl0KxQHMFksICs1tRTB0Flhdlp6G8Lp9vr1wWoRHAcgB3TDOfFAwnyMGsCHcbgwOIIVpGDRBAFyNQKZHLZyrABKEAQNLkAGkADSnekfeR2A5KJSytTSoWokXIAAKBGOUDAB2lEFVAAo1ORKD4-Pp5aAEt1kNKAJT6LGSkBMHnNELtAC8FHqflCTsW4QAdI5glyQANyFAIGAxFB2rasA04AMKuyQJy2sgABZ2Zw2ObZq3kCMunCdBA6BJySbm9AwZBwhEgObygDkmY2UD76r9uh6pVYHo06BcXqMvoQaeT4ErfmQweuWi0AEJkBTO-DEVRE8gl-hUWA1zJw-FIzHtLoN2OIKfvb7YwDnNnn5-PhbzxXK9QxkR0706N1cxIIA)